# How to access nested functions in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Say, we have a Vue.js component built this way:

```
export default {
  watch: {
    // vars
    }
  },
  methods: {
    functionOne: function() {
        function nestedFuncOne(p, q) {
            // doing something
            }
        },
    functionTwo: function() {
        function nestedFuncTwo(r, s) {
            // doing something
            }
        nestedFuncOne(param1, param2);  // how to call it?
        }
    },
(...)
```

How should an inner function from the first method be called from inside of second method? `this` seems not to give desired output here.

Comment: Could you explain why you need these nested?

Comment: You need to return this function to access it outside.

Comment: @BertEvans: In short, it was an old pure JS code migrated to Vue.js. The helper functions check DOM elements' ids, fetch data from JSON file and assign values based on ids.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3: are you saying, the nested functions should be on the same level as functionOne and *Two?

Comment: I think your easiest route is just to move them out and make them methods.

Comment: I'm just saying, that you can only access the function inside the functions from outside when you return it. See it as a variable, declared inside the function scope. You don't have access to this function except if you return the function or any object containing a reference to that function. But as @BertEvans said, just move the functions outside to the `methods` object.

Comment: Yes,, this is not a vuejs issue it is pure js!